# Creating report to pull activities

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

Iam trying to create report that pulls activities related to account and also activities related to contact and opportunity from that account, is this possible? i tried to create custom report type but it doesn't seems to be possible

Comment: As a report, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All activities related to Contact and Opportunity are automatically rolled up to the related Account as well.

So you can just use the existing standard report type **'Activities with Accounts'** and that will, by default, also show the activities linked to all Contacts and Opportunities of the Account.

Comment: Activities with Accounts report type just shows only activities related to that account , it doesn't shows that are related to contact and opp within that account, i already tried this and doesn't works

Comment: That's strange. I tried it as well and it did work in my org. Here's what I did: 1) create a task from the Contact page. 2) check the Account page. The task is displayed there as well in the Open Activities related list. 3) run the report of (standard) type 'Activities with Accounts'. The task is displayed there as well..  I followed the same scenario for Opportunities and that worked the same.

Comment: Yup you are right. Tasks were not showing in my case since users are deactivated, thanks for your help

Comment: ah.. good to know that!